# Unable to boot Windows XP after installing ubuntu 10.10

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub

I have ubuntu 8.10 & Windows XP installed on my PC. I formatted the C:\ partition and installed a new fresh copy of Win XP.

After that I was not able to login to ubuntu 8.10. It is clear that Win XP overwrote the MBR.

I tried to re-install the boot loader (Grub) again by boot ubuntu 10.10 CD. Finally, I was able to boot both ubuntu version 8.10 and 10.10. However, I was not able to boot Win XP.

There is an entry in grun menu of ubuntu 10.10 specific for WinXP, but when I press enter to boot Windows I get back to grub menu.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please add the output of 'sudo fdisk -l' and the content of '/boot/grub/menu.lst' to your question?

Comment: When you're in the grub menu, also click e to edit the windows entry and let us know what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your grub.conf you will find windows xp grub menu and put this

```
title windows xp
root (hd0,1)
savedefault
makeactive
chainloader +1
```

check this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grubconf-for-windows-vista-or-xp-dual-boot/